# How to restore a directory many revision after?

Tags: svn

I have a strange svn behaviour :

For some reason, I removed a directory times ago:

```
cd /repos/a  (correspond to the url svn+ssh://server/repos/a)
ls gives 'b' which is under svn.
svn rm b
svn ci -m "" -> I am at revision 701
```

I work a little till, let's say revision 740
Then I want to get back directory 'b'

first I check, I can list it within an old revision of the repository:

```
cd /repos/a
svn ls -r 700 svn+ssh://server/repos/a : OK I can see directory 'b'
```

but

```
svn ls -r 700 svn+ssh://server/repos/a/b :
svn : file not found : revision 740, path '/repos/a/b'
```

why? I have same message with svn copy or svn merge

The funny thing is when I use recursive ls :

```
svn ls -r 700 -R svn+ssh://server/repos/a :
```

the listing shows 'b' as well as ALL files in it...

I am using svn 1.4.6 what should I do to get back 'b'?

Comment: Anyway upgrade your SVN to much more up-to-date version: 1.6.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to specify a peg revision.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html

Try:

```
svn ls -r 700 svn+ssh://server/repos/a/b@700
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, your link explained a lot of things. I succeded to restore my directory. :)